# How to communicate between php and my application on windows server

Tags: c#, php, windows

So basically i want to make a website that upload a file (an executable one .exe)from a user, when it finish upload i have to open this file on the same server (windows server) since my application run on windows 
The file will be encrypted by my C# application and i want to be returned to the user by link to they can download it.
My question are: 
How to communicate? between them 
My application have to be a command line ? 
Have you to use API? 
Any useful link or some similar source to learn more are very welcome 
Thank you a lot community SO.
BV1,

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you should create a web service which could be consumed using your PHP application. This service could be a WCF Service exposing some methods. Look at below code:
[ConsumeWCF service from PHP](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/442208/ConsumeWCF-service-from-PHP)